# Can you change your party's starting positions?

Tags: mario-plus-rabbids-kingdom-battle

In most battles, it would be advantageous for one party member to start in one spot as opposed to another. Is it possible to swap their start locations or influence it in any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can see, you can get a different party layout if you choose 2 rabbids as opposed to 1 mushroom kingdom member and 1 rabbid. It doesn't appear to be a fine-grained control but it can help in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify Seiyria's answer, the level starting positions are basically fixed and ordered 1-2-3. The starting positions are filled in your team roster order, which is determined by reading the selected characters from left to right in the team selection screen.  Mario is on the far left, so is always position one.  The next selected character as you read from left to right is number two, and the rightmost one is number three.

**Update:** *It appears that Luigi, Peach, and Yoshi are always assigned to position 3 regardless of party selection*

With this in mind, you can exert *limited* control over the starting positions. If you really want, for example, Rabbid Mario to start in position #2, then select a party member that sequentially comes after Rabbid Mario on the team selection screen to be your third member.

Comment: This doesn’t appear to be true, at least not with what I’m trying. Right before 2-8 where Peach gets inserted, it swaps out Luigi no matter which Rabbid you select (even Rabid Mario, who’s sequentially after Luigi). So it seems like the Rabbids are always before Luigi.

Comment: @JeradRose Having just retested, if you have selected a non-rabbid as a party member (Luigi, Peach, Yoshi), they are always in position 3.  If you select two rabbids, my original description is accurate (My example has been updated)

Comment: Yeah, I also figured out (after getting Peach) that you have to have at least one Rabbid. You can’t have a party with Mario, Luigi, and Peach. Thematically makes sense, but strategically unfortunate in some cases.